# MongoDB - Query array that contains nothing but specific values (JavaScript)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new to Mongodb and Node. Also new to this forum so please be patient with me.

When I have documents like these:

```
{_id: '1', name: 'doc1', values: [{name: 'val1', value: 'x'}]}
{_id: '2', name: 'doc2', values: [{name: 'val1', value: 'x'}, {name: 'val2', 
value: 'x'}]}
{_id: '3', name: 'doc3', values: [{name: 'val1', value: 'x'}, {name: 'val2', 
value: 'x'}, {name: 'val3', value: 'x'}]}
{_id: '4', name: 'doc4', values: [{name: 'val1', value: 'x'}, {name: 'val3', 
value: 'x'}]}
```

how do I search documents which contain not (necessarily) all but only given values like:

```
db.collection('col1').find(val1, val2);
```

and get the results:

```
doc1, doc2
```

the only way, I found to accomplish this is the following:

```
db.collection('col1').find({'values.name': {$nin: {['val3', EveryOtherPossibleValue,...]}}})
```

but I still search for a better (and - because EveryOtherPossibleValue could be a lot of values - shorter) query to do the same thing

help would be appreciated

Comment: `db.collection('coll1').find({ "values.name":  { "$all": ["val1","val2"] }, "values":  { "$size": 2 } })`. So matches both values and because it's only 2 items in length then those are the only ones. There's a duplicate around here somewhere because I know I've answered the same thing before.

Comment: but this would not match doc1. I dont want to match all but only values given in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, i found the answer:

```
db.collection('col1').find("values":{"$not":{"$elemMatch":{"name":{$nin:['val1', 'val2']}}}}})
```

This query will match only documents, where NO value in the given field does NOT match any of the given values. -> all values in the document match any of the given values in the query.

Thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
db.collection('col1').aggregate([{$unwind:'$values'},{$match:{$in:['val1','val2']}},{$group:{_id:"$name"}}])
```

Comment: just tryed it. Mongo gives me an Error, that says 'unknown top level operator $in'

Comment: also tryed db.collection('col1').aggregate([{$unwind:'$values'},{$match: {'name': {$in: ['val1, 'val2']}}}]) but this goves me an empty result

Comment: try this 'db.getCollection('col1').aggregate([
{$unwind:'$values'},
{$match:{'values.name':{$in:["val1","val2"]}}},
{$group:{_id:"$name"}},{$sort:{_id:1}},{$limit:2}])'

Comment: sadly, this does not give me the expected results. this query still matches documents containing values not specified in the query

Comment: All the documents has val1 in it so if we check for val1 all the doc1,doc2,doc3,doc4 will be in result right then what is the problem you are facing can you elobrate

Comment: ok, i'll explain this from the use case:
i want to build an app, that can tell me, for example, what i can build out of my legos. I want to search for the sets, i have and get results that contain only manuals for contructions, i can build with the legos, i have.
But on the other side, the constructions dont need to contain all Legos, i have got